# Bayesian: Joint Smoothing Recursion

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

**Note:** I am dealing with a state space model/hidden Markov model, where process $x_t$ is only dependent on $x_{t-1}$ and $y_t$ is only dependent on $x_t$.

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
p(x_{0:t}|y_{0:t})& = \frac{p(y_t|x_{0:t},y_{0:t-1})
p(x_{0:t}|,y_{0:t-1}) }{p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})} ~~~\mbox{(bayes)}\\
 & = \frac{p(y_t|x_{0:t},y_{0:t-1})
p(x_{t}|x_{0:t-1},y_{0:t-1}) p(x_{0:t-1}|y_{0:t-1})}{p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})}~~~\mbox{(bayes)} \\
&=\frac{p(y_t|x_{t})
p(x_{t}|x_{t-1}) p(x_{0:t-1}|y_{0:t-1})}{p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})}~~~\mbox{(conditional independence)} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

**Question:** What is $p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})$ as an integral? I saw [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF2011.pdf) that they wrote $$p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})=\int p(y_t|x_t)p(x_t|x_{t-1})p(x_{t-1}|y_{0:t-1}) dx_{t-1:t} \,.$$ How do they get to that: can someone write a step-by- step derivation (actively stating what steps they used to simplify)?

I find it unusual how they simplified $p(x_{0:t-1}|y_{0:t-1})$ to $p(x_{t-1}|y_{0:t-1})$ and how they knew to integrate away $dx_{t-1:t}$.

If I were to guess what $p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})$ was I would have written

$$p(y_t|y_{0:t-1})=\int p(y_t|x_{0:t},y_{0:t-1})p(x_{0:t}|,y_{0:t-1}) dx_{0:t}$$

However, I do not know how to continue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is
\begin{align*}
p(y_t|y_{0:t-1}) &= \int p(y_t,x_t,x_{t-1}|y_{0:t-1}) dx_{t-1:t}  \\
&= \int p(y_t|x_{t-1},x_t, y_{0:t-1}) p(x_t|x_{t-1},y_{0:t-1})p(x_{t-1}|y_{0:t-1}) dx_{t-1:t} \\
&= \int p(y_t|x_t)p(x_t|x_{t-1})p(x_{t-1}|y_{0:t-1}) dx_{t-1:t} && \tag{1}
\end{align*}
with the third equality being because there's a lot of conditional independence.

Your way is also true. But you're missing the conditional independence again.
\begin{align*}
\int p(y_t|x_{0:t},y_{0:t-1})p(x_{0:t}|,y_{0:t-1}) dx_{0:t} &= \int p(y_t|x_{t})p(x_{0:t}|,y_{0:t-1}) dx_{0:t} \\
&= \int p(y_t|x_{t})p(x_t|x_{0:t-1},y_{0:t-1})p(x_{0:t-1}|,y_{0:t-1}) dx_{0:t} \\
&= \int p(y_t|x_{t})p(x_t|x_{t-1})p(x_{0:t-1}|,y_{0:t-1}) dx_{0:t} && \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Notice that (1) and (2) are the same.